# Каким методом можно узнать что окно root было перемещено, свернуто или закрыто?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как можно зафиксировать перемещении, сворачивание и закрытии окна, а затем выполнить функцию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- закрытие окна:

  ```
  root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_exit)  # call root.quit()/root.destory()
  ```
- перемещение (в том числе изменение размера):

  ```
  root.bind('<Configure>', on_move_or_resize)
  ```
- если программно "свернуть"/развернуть окно с помощью `root.withdraw`/`root.deiconify` методов:

  ```
  root.bind('<Map>', on_deiconify) # and on start too
  root.bind('<Unmap>', on_withdraw)
  ```

Если просто с помощью кнопки в интерфейсе свернуть, то из всех событий, перечисленных в [tcl/Tk `bind()` man](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm#M7), только FocusIn/FocusOut генерируются в моём окружении (Ubuntu Unity) и `root.state()` остаётся `normal`. В выводе утилит типа `xprop`/`xwininfo` также ничего не меняется.

Comment: `root.bind('<Unmap>', on_withdraw) ` почему вызывается несколько раз и как это исправить?

Comment: @оаавирыыва "как исправить?" — рассказать что вы делали, почему думаете что один раз должен вызываться, рассказать о вашем окружении (OS, python версия), привести минимальный пример кода и всё это как отдельный Satck Overflow вопрос опубликовать.

Comment: После замены `Satck Overflow` на Stack Overflow в моём комментарии, какой момент не ясен с тем что там сказано? Ошибку вы должны в несколько строк воспроизвести (начните с нуля, хоть с одной кнопки) [mcve]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807656/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-curtail-win-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7

Comment: Я пользуюсь windows 10, Python 3.6.4 Функция должна один раз вызываться при сложении окна, а она несколько раз вызывается. Ваши инструкции понятны, но почему-то в одной ситуации функция вызывается один раз, а в своем коде несколько

Comment: Я вроде понял причину

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807656/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-curtail-win-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7 проверьте еще раз

Comment: Вы не знаете как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `bind(<Configure>,self.func)` чтобы воспроизводить сигнал при изменения окна(перемещение окна, размер окна и т.д.)

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("200x200")

        self.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.func())

    def func(self):
        x = self.winfo_width()
        y = self.winfo_height()
        if x >= 795 and y >= 308:
            print(x, y)
            print('было допущенно совпадение')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Main()

    root.mainloop()
```

---

вывод

```
было допущенно совпадение
1201 317
было допущенно совпадение
1201 314
было допущенно совпадение
1202 311
было допущенно совпадение
```

Пример использования сигнал на закрытия окна и изменения размера

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("200x200")
        button = tk.Button(self, text='Закрыть', command=lambda: self.destroy())
        button.pack()
        self.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.func())
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: print('окно должно быть закрыто'))

    def func(self):
        x = self.winfo_width()
        y = self.winfo_height()
        if (x > 200 or x < 200) or (y > 200 or y < 200):
            self.geometry("200x200")
            print('Запрещено изменения окна')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Main()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @оаавирыыва вам нужно чтобы при сворачивании окна происходила функция?

Comment: Мне нужно при перемещении, при сворачивании и еще при закрытии окна.

Comment: Так что, знаешь как?