# Почему функция curtail_win вызывается несколько раз?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, bind, listbox

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

class tk_():
    def __init__(self):
        Button(text="press").pack()
        root.bind('<Unmap>', self.curtail_win)

    def curtail_win(self,event):
        print("Error")

    def bind_all(self):
        print("Bind")

tk = tk_()

root.mainloop()
```

Почему-то функция `curtail_win` вызывается столько раз сколько виджетов на нем + само окно

Вывод:

```
Error
Error
```

Функция вызвалась 2 раза, т.е Окно + Кнопка = 2 раза вызова функции

---

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

class tk_():
    def __init__(self):
        Button(text="Press").pack()
        Button(text="New").pack()
        root.bind('<Unmap>', self.curtail_win)

    def curtail_win(self,event):
        print("Error")

    def bind_all(self):
        print("Bind")



tk = tk_()


root.mainloop()
```

Здесь уже 3 раза
Вывод:

```
Error
Error
Error
```

Здесь уже: Окно + Кнопка + Кнопка = 3

Comment: @jfs Поняли проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У события есть атрибут widget, который показывает к чему оно относится. К примеру, если `self` это ваше окно, то можно сразу вернуться, если не тот widget указан:

```
def on_unmap(self, event):
    if event.widget is not self:
        return
```